# Stream data from Couchbase

Tags: php, symfony, couchbase

My Symfony project stores PDFs on a Couchbase server and I want to stream them to the client instead of simply load them in memory and redistribute them directly. The goal is to not overload my server memory by only transiting small (something like 64ko) chunks of data.

I've seen some old topics about "handling that to Nginx" but I am unfamiliar with that process. I know also that Guzzle offers a Stream object that may be the solution I seek.

How would you handle that situation?

Comment: How about using `Guzzle Stream Decorators` such as `BufferStream` and `DroppingStream` as described at [Guzzle Stream Decorators](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/psr7.html#streams) and [Stream Decorators Usage](https://github.com/guzzle/psr7#bufferstream)

Comment: I don't really need fancy features provided by Buffer or Dropping... But the main Stream object is close to what I need. The issue is that it needs some resource (PHP speaking) to be instanciated and Couchbase doesn't return a resource.